# Recharts: have both outside and inside label on Pie chart

Tags: reactjs, charts, recharts

I am creating a pie chart with the help of the Recharts library. This Pie chart shows the distribution of various sources of income. Currently I only show a label on the outside of the name (img 1, code can be seen in linked code sandbox).

However, I would also like to have a percentage number in the center of every piece of the pie. (paint example of desired outcome at img 2). How would I achieve this with recharts?

[Code sandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-cache-qvqu0j?file=/src/App.js)

[image: As it is now]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code hope its help[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXqSA.png)
with the help of labelList

```
<PieChart width={350} height={380}>
    <Pie
      dataKey="volume"
      isAnimationActive={true}
      data={currentPieValue()}
      outerRadius={80}
      fill="#08B8A1"
      label
      margin={{ top: 5, right: 30, left: 20, bottom: 5 }}
    >
      <LabelList
        dataKey="name"
        position="right"
        style={{ fontSize: "10px" }}
      />
      {currentPieValue().map((entry, index) => (
        <Cell key={`cell-${index}`} fill={colors[index]} />
      ))}
    </Pie>
    <Tooltip />
  </PieChart>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Additionally, in your code, you are using the `index` as part of the key. It's a bad idea to use the array index since it doesn't uniquely identify your elements. In cases where the array is sorted or an element is added to the beginning of the array, the index will be changed even though the element representing that index may be the same. This results in unnecessary renders.

Answer (score 1):

I have found two possible solutions, both by adding the LabelList inside the Pie tag:

1. Put the percentage directly of each one in the data and then in the dataKey of the LabelList refer to this percentage.
2. Create an arrow function where to calculate the percentage in relation to the value and the total, which we will put as the second parameter, will calculate the percentage.

- With the toFixed function we round to two decimals
- With the replace function we exchange the point for the comma to display it.

In the css we add the following class to change the type and font size of the percentages:

```
.label-percentage {
   font-family: arial;
   font-size: 20px;
}
```

[Code sandbox Solution](https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-herschel-w6j7se?file=/src/App.js)

Result of the solution in photo
[image]